# Cannot assign class instance to its protocol type?

Tags: ios, generics, swift, interface, compiler-errors

Please see self containing example below. Compiler reports an error on the last line (marked by `COMPILE ERROR`) where I am assigning an instance of `SimpleTrain` to a protocol type that it (in my best judgement) conforms to. How can I make it compile? What am I doing wrong? Or is this compiler issue?

```
protocol Train {
    typealias CarriageType

    func addCarriage(carriage: CarriageType)
    func shortTrain<ShortType: Train where ShortType.CarriageType == CarriageType>() -> ShortType
}

class SimpleTrain<T> : Train {
    typealias CarriageType = T
    private var carriages: [T] = [T]()

    func addCarriage(carriage: T) {
       carriages.append(carriage)
    }

    func shortTrain<ShortType: Train where ShortType.CarriageType == CarriageType>() -> ShortType {
        let short = SimpleTrain<T>()
        short.addCarriage(carriages[0])
        return short //COMPILE ERROR: SimpleTrain<T> is not convertible to 'ShortType'
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Even when I explicitly downcast the `shortTrain`'s return type above (so that last line of code snippet above reads `return short as ShortType`) as [suggested by Antonio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26271483/311865) there is still compilation error when calling function `shortTrain`:

```
let s = SimpleTrain<String>()
s.addCarriage("Carriage 1")
s.addCarriage("Carriage 2")

let a = s.shortTrain() //ERROR: Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type 'Train'
let b = s.shortTrain<SimpleTrain<String>>() //ERROR: cannot explicitly specialize a generic function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you want to read the [canonical thread](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/230611) on this from devforums. You particularly want to skip around to read jckarter's comments.

Now to the edited question:

```
let a = s.shortTrain() //ERROR: Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type 'Train'
```

This is because you haven't given the compiler enough information to determine the type of `a`. Think through what it sees:

```
func shortTrain<ShortType: Train where ShortType.CarriageType == CarriageType>() -> ShortType {
let a = s.shortTrain()
```

The compiler needs to figure out the type of `a` at compile time, and it can't handle abstract types. It needs a fully specified type for `ShortType` (everything nailed down; all the generics specified, all the type aliases resolved). It looks around, and it sees some constraints on `ShortType`, but it doesn't see anything that actually gives a type. All it has is `a`, which isn't giving it any hints.

So unfortunately, that leaves you having to tell it explicitly what you want to happen.

```
let a: SimpleTrain<String> = s.shortTrain()
```

That's probably the opposite of what you were going for, but it's about all you can do in Swift right now. The Swift team has indicated (many times) that they are well aware of these issues with associated types (and several other related weaknesses in the type system). They're specifically aware of the Scala type system which can handle these things and has a lot in common with the current Swift type system (though in my experience, getting complex path-dependent associated types to work in Scala can also lead to hair tearing).

That said, it's not exactly obvious from your example what you planned to do with this functionality. Would some Trains return a different type as their shortTrain()?

I find that these problems often blow up in the general case, but tend to be quite solvable in the specific cases for the app in front of you. It's hard to build really arbitrary types in Swift in code that could solve every problem, but it often works out when you focus on the types you'll really need. For example, if `shortTrain()` returned `Self`, this obviously gets simpler. If the caller knows the desired resulting type, then an `init(shorten:)` can probably handle it. A protocol method like `shortCarriages() -> [CarriageType]` may provide a good bridge. Stay flexible on your design, and one of them will almost certainly work out.

Comment: Thank you for this answer Rob. It answered all my questions (including some I might have asked elsewhere in the future, for example what does Swift team think about this). Unfortunately, I cannot provide any more specific information. I provided artificial example in order to erase all business related information. However , the example given is as near as possible and I state that the product is a library and I can hardly require users to specify type explicitly for many method calls. I have found another way around. Still protocols with open type-aliases to be used as types would be great

Answer (score 4):

An explicit downcast of either the variable:

```
let short = SimpleTrain<T>() as ShortType
```

or the return value:

```
return short as ShortType
```

solves the problem.

**Update**

When I was answering to the question, I wondered myself how the `Train` protocol can be used as a return type, being it typealiased.

Look at this code:

```
protocol ProtocolWithNoAlias {        
}

protocol ProtocolWithAlias {
    typealias AliasType
}

var x: ProtocolWithNoAlias?
var y: ProtocolWithAlias?
```

The last line is reported as a compilation error:

```
Protocol 'ProtocolWithAlias' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self os associated type requirements
```

which means you cannot use `ProtocolWithAlias` as a concrete type, which in turn means you cannot declare variables having `ProtocolWithAlias` type, and consequently it doesn't make sense to define function returning it.

I cannot find any mention about that in the official documentation, but I am sure I read somewhere, I just don't remember where.

Conclusion: I interpret the error you're having troubles with:

```
SimpleTrain<T> is not convertible to 'ShortType'
```

as a direct consequence of the protocol being typealiased.

**Note that this is my personal opinion**, since I am unable at this moment to prove it besides that code snippet testing protocol with and without aliases.

Comment: Thank you for this Antonio. While it is definitely practical solution (and the one I will use if not better is found) I believe that an explicit downcast should not be required in a situation when the compiler can indeed infer implicitly that the type assigned is fitting the variable.

Comment: Please read updated answer - not sure if it makes sense though :)

Comment: Through personal, it is very good opinion and analyses indeed. Furthermore, if we continue along those lines: Typealiased protocols are replacement for generic protocols (Apple engineers declaring they are *better*). Your conclusions means that they cannot be used as types (of constants, variables, methods...). In Java or C# that is an equivalent of being able to use only non-genetic interfaces as types. If this analyses are correct this is IMHO serious omission in Swift. I would be very interested in getting opinion of somebody creditable on Swift about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you *have* to use a Protocol?  I don't have a very good grasp of type theory, but the problem seems to come back to the topic of "higher kinded types", per the discussion on the Apple thread and from above.

That said, if you can try to approximate using an abstract base class (with the caveat that is it not actually abstract, and does not work for structs), with the following form:

```
class AnyTrain<CarriageType> {
    
    func addCarriage(carriage: CarriageType) {}
    func shortTrain() -> AnyTrain<CarriageType>  { return AnyTrain<CarriageType>() }
}

class SimpleTrain<T> : AnyTrain<T>, Printable {
    private var carriages: [T] = [T]()
    
    override func addCarriage(carriage: T) {
        carriages.append(carriage)
    }
    
    override func shortTrain() -> AnyTrain<T> {
        let short = SimpleTrain<T>()
        short.addCarriage(carriages[0])
        return short //COMPILE ERROR: SimpleTrain<T> is not convertible to 'ShortType'
    }
    
    var description:String {
        return "Train: \(carriages)"
    }
}


let train = SimpleTrain<Int>()
train.addCarriage(1)
train.addCarriage(2)
train.addCarriage(3)

let shortTrain = train.shortTrain()
println(shortTrain)

// obviously you can refer to it as the base
let anotherTrain:AnyTrain<Int> = SimpleTrain<Int>()
anotherTrain.addCarriage(3)
anotherTrain.addCarriage(2)
anotherTrain.addCarriage(1)

let anotherShortTrain = anotherTrain.shortTrain()
println(anotherShortTrain)
```

This outputs:

> Train: [1]
>
> Train: [3]

I have experimented with this technique for cases where I have abstract hierarchies where one type is in common, and other other differs but does not affect the function signatures.  By using an "abstract class", I can create an array of "any type with this one generic type in common (while the others can differ)"