# How to pass protocol with associated type (generic protocol) as parameter in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I have to pass an interface as a parameter to a function. Interface is generic a.k.a. has a associated type. I couldn't find a good way to do that. Here is my code:

```
protocol IObserver : class {
    typealias DelegateT
    ...
}

class Observer: IObserver {
    typealias DelegateT = IGeneralEventsDelegate // IGeneralEventsDelegate is a protocol
    ...
}

func notify(observer: IObserver) { ... } // here I need a type for observer param
```

I found that this will work:

```
func notify<T: IObserver where T.DelegateT == IGeneralEventsDelegate>(observer: T) { ... }
```

, but come on that is too complicated. What if I want to save this param in class variable, should I make the whole class generic, just because of this function.

It is true that I'm C++ developer and I'm new to the Swift language, but the way the things are done are far too complicated and user unfriendly ... or I'm too stupid :)

Comment: I think so too every time. Inconvenience really.
In terms of C++, I think Swift's `protocol` looks like `concept`. And a `extension` having a type conformed to a `protocol` is similar to `concept_map`. These facilities are useful to realize compile-time polymorphism.
In many cases, however, we would rather want a mechanism like `pure virtual class` + `multiple inheritance`, corresponds Java's `interface`, to realize runtime polymorphism. But Swift might have no mechanisms corresponding to these for generic types..

Comment: See my related answer on this here ---> http://stackoverflow.com/a/34995198/5389500

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use `typealias` in a protocol to make it generic-like, then you cannot use it as a variable type until the associated type is resolved. As you have probably experienced, using a protocol with associated type to define a variable (or function parameter) results in a compilation error:

> Protocol 'MyProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self os associated type requirements

That means you cannot use it as a concrete type.

So the only 2 ways I am aware of to use a protocol with associated type as a concrete type are:

- indirectly, by creating a class that implements it. Probably not what you have planned to do
- making explicit the associated type like you did in your func

See also related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26271483/148357