# How to create a function that returns a generic protocol type?

Tags: swift

In the following code, I have a generic protocol `Var` and it have a private implementation class `LambdaVar`. Now I want to have a function that return an instance of the `LambdaVar` without expose it publicly.

But I can't find a way to define a function that return a generic protocol type.

```
public protocol Var {
    typealias ValueType
    var value : ValueType { get }
}

struct LambdaVar<T> : Var {
    let _get : Void -> T
    init(_ f : Void -> T)
    {
        _get = f
    }
    var value : T {
        get {
            return _get()
        }
    }
}

public func transform<T : Var, U>(v : T, f : T.ValueType -> U) -> Var<U> {
    return LambdaVar<U>() { f(v.value) }                       // ^^^^^^ what to put here?
}
```

Error:

```
Playground execution failed: <EXPR>:26:67: error: cannot specialize non-generic type 'Var'
public func transform<T : Var, U>(v : T, f : T.ValueType -> U) -> Var<U> {
                                                                  ^
<EXPR>:26:67: error: protocol 'Var' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
public func transform<T : Var, U>(v : T, f : T.ValueType -> U) -> Var<U> {
```

Comment: I think what you are trying to achieve is not doable in swift - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26271483/148357). A protocol with generic cannot be used as a concrete type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create simple wrapper type of `Var` like `SequenceOf<T>`:

```
struct VarOf<T>:Var {
    let f:Void->T
    init<V:Var where V.ValueType == T>(_ v:V) {
        f = { v.value }
    }
    var value:T {
        return f()
    }
}

func transform<T : Var, U>(v : T, f : T.ValueType -> U) -> VarOf<U> {
    return VarOf(LambdaVar<U>({ f(v.value) }))
}

let intVar = VarOf(LambdaVar({ 12 }))
let floatVar = transform(intVar, { Float($0) })
floatVar.value // -> 12.0
```