# Can't create an Array of types conforming to a Protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

I have the following protocol and a class that conforms to it:

```
protocol Foo{
    typealias BazType

    func bar(x:BazType) ->BazType
}


class Thing: Foo {
    func bar(x: Int) -> Int {
        return x.successor()
    }
}
```

When I try to create an Array of foos, I get an odd error:

```
var foos: Array<Foo> = [Thing()]
```

> Protocol Foo can only be used as a generic constraint because it has
>   Self or associated type requirements.

OK, so it can only be used if it has an associated type requirement (which it does), but for some reason this is an error?? WTF?!

I'm not sure I fully understand what the compiler is trying to tell me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot assign class instance to its protocol type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267597/cannot-assign-class-instance-to-its-protocol-type)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's say, if we could put an instance of `Thing` into array `foos`, what will happen?

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype BazType
    func bar(x:BazType) -> BazType
}

class Thing: Foo {
    func bar(x: Int) -> Int {
        return x.successor()
    }
}

class AnotherThing: Foo {
    func bar(x: String) -> String {
        return x
    }
}

var foos: [Foo] = [Thing()]
```

Because `AnotherThing` conforms to `Foo` too, so we can put it into `foos` also.

```
foos.append(AnotherThing())
```

Now we grab a `foo` from `foos` randomly.

```
let foo = foos[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(foos.count - 1)))]
```

and I'm going to call method `bar`, can you tell me that I should send a string or an integer to `bar`?

`foo.bar("foo")` or `foo.bar(1)`

Swift can't.

So it can only be used as a generic constraint.

What scenario requires a protocol like this?

**Example:**

```
class MyClass<T: Foo> {
        let fooThing: T?

        init(fooThing: T? = nil) {
                self.fooThing = fooThing
        }
        
        func myMethod() {
                let thing = fooThing as? Thing // ok
                thing?.bar(1) // fine
                
                let anotherThing = fooThing as? AnotherThing // no problem
                anotherThing?.bar("foo") // you can do it
                
                // but you can't downcast it to types which doesn't conform to Foo
                let string = fooThing as? String // this is an error
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been playing with your code trying to understand how to implement the protocol. I found that you can't use Typealias as a generic type because it is just an alias not a type by itself. So if you declare the Typealias outside your protocol and your class you can effectively use it in your code without any problem.

**Note:** the Typealias has the `Int` type in its declaration, that way you can always use the alias instead of the Int type and use all of its associated methods and functions.

Here's how I make it work:

```
typealias BazType = Int

protocol Foo{
  func bar(x:BazType) -> BazType
}

class Thing: Foo {
  func bar(x: BazType) -> BazType {
    return x.successor()
  }
}

let elements: Array<Foo> = [Thing(), Thing()]
```

Comment: in this code BazType is just Int and not a variable type.