# Array with associatedtype protocol

Tags: java, swift, swift2, swift-protocols

I'am coming from java and I have little difficulties to learn the patterns.

I have the first protocol

```
protocol Interval
{

}
```

And the second:

```
protocol Event
{
    associatedtype IntervalType: Interval

    var interval: IntervalType

    func doSomething(param: IntervalType )
}
```

How can i make an array with the type Event?

I took a look at the type-erase and the solution that it gives it to create a struct like this one:

```
public struct AnyEvent<intervalType: Interval>: Event {...}
```

But it only gives me the possibility to create an array with any event type and only one type of Interval, I want to make an array with any kind of Events that could contain any kind of Intervals, something like: `[AnyEvent]` or `[AnyEvent<Interval>]`

I also want to ask if there is a possibility to make Event extend Equatable and define it in the type-erase.

**Edit**:

Hoping someone is good at both swift and java, and can provide a translated pattern for this:

A simple common interval interface:

```
interface ReadableInterval {...}
```

Two types that confirms the readable interval:

```
class Interval implements ReadableInterval {...}

class MutableInterval implements: ReadableInterval {...}
```

A common events interface:

```
interface ReadablEvent
{
   ReadableInterval getInterval();
}
```

Two types of events that could have different intervals, with the specialized return type of the methods:

```
class Event implements: ReadablEvent
{

   private Interval interval = new Interval();

   Interval getInterval()
   {
       return interval;
   }
}

class MutableEvent implements: ReadablEvent
{

   private MutableInterval interval = new MutableInterval();

   MutableInterval getInterval()
   {
       return interval;
   }
}
```

and then i want to have a list or array with the both Event and MutableEvent like:

```
ArrayList<ReadableEvent>
```

or

```
ReadableEvent[]
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know in Swift you cannot declare an array of a protocols with an associated type (please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865779/cant-create-an-array-of-types-conforming-to-a-protocol-in-swift) for more details)

However you can declare a new protocol like this

```
protocol AnyEvent {
    var interval: Interval { get }
    func doSomething(param: Interval )
}
```

Your 3 protocols should now look like this

```
protocol Interval {

}

protocol AnyEvent {
    var interval: Interval { get }
    func doSomething(param: Interval )
}

protocol Event: AnyEvent {
    associatedtype IntervalType: Interval
    var interval: IntervalType { get }
    func doSomething(param: IntervalType )
}
```

### Usage

To use these protocols we need some structs (or classes) that conform to them

```
struct TimeInterval: Interval { }
struct TapEvent: AnyEvent {
    var interval: Interval = TimeInterval()
    func doSomething(param: Interval) {
        print("It's a tap")
    }
}
struct GestureEvent: AnyEvent {
    var interval: Interval = TimeInterval()
    func doSomething(param: Interval) {
        print("It's a gesture")
    }
}
```

Now we can

```
var events = [AnyEvent]()
events.append(TapEvent())
events.append(GestureEvent())
for event in events {
    event.doSomething(TimeInterval())
}
```

> It's a tap
>
> It's a gesture

### I also want to ask if there is a possibility to make Event extend Equatable and define it in the type-erase

Yes you just need to add the declaration

```
protocol Event: AnyEvent, Equatable {
    associatedtype IntervalType: Interval
    var interval: IntervalType { get }
    func doSomething(param: IntervalType )
}
```

Now you are forcing every struct o class conform to `Event` to be `Equatable`.

Comment: Can you make me please an example for a EventClass or EventStruct that implement Event and confirms it? TimeInterval will be a good typealias for the IntervalType

Comment: @4bottiglie Now I don't have my Mac. I'll provide you with an example tomorrow

Comment: @4bottiglie: I haven't found a way yet :)

Comment: Swift makes it hard as hell. The only solution I found is that to skip Event protocol and have a new variable instead of associatedtype, like Interval for the Interval and timeInterval for the TimeInterval as properties that share the same private _timeInterval variable. But it's ugly to have a new one for every extended class.