# How to type generic protocol to be able to use them as return type

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

The following code does not work. 
I come from a Java world and I don't understand why generic protocol cannot be returned as long as I specify the typealias ?

I tried `associatedType Element: User`, `typealias Element = User` in the UserDao to specialize it but everytime the getTest() method return the same error :

`Protocol 'UserDao' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

What's the good way to do it in swift ?

```
import Foundation

protocol HasId {
}

protocol BaseDao {
    associatedtype Element: HasId
}

protocol UserDao: BaseDao {
    // already tried these solutions...
    // associatedType Element: User
    // typealias Element = User
}

class User: HasId {}

class Test {
    func getTest() -> UserDao? { // Error is on the return type
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Error explains it quite clearly `Protocol 'UserDao' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`. Already explained - Please refer link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725803/how-to-use-generic-protocol-as-a-variable-type

Comment: Here is very good article, which may solve your problem : https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/an-alternative-to-type-erasure-for-generic-protocols-a9a48e96618a

Answer (score 2):

```
error: protocol 'UserDao' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

The compiler gives you the error above.

You can't use a protocol with an associated type as a function parameter or a return type, because it needs to know which typealias to associate to the protocol.

It seems frustrating if you come from the Java world but the solution is to use a class to define the typealias associated to your type.

```
protocol BaseDao {
    associatedtype Element: HasId
}

class UserDao: BaseDao {
    typealias Element = User
}
```

[You can see a more complete answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26267597/cannot-assign-class-instance-to-its-protocol-type/26271483#26271483)

Comment: This will work, but I want to create differents implementations of UserDao : MemoryUserDao, FirebaseUserDao, .... so each implements UserDao protocol. But as Preskhya points out, there is no way to achieve this easily in swift. Thanks anyway !

Comment: @Spoke44 Maybe if it's a new project you should review your dao architecture. I wrote this kind of system many times, and maybe you could have only one Dao object type (one for each table), but gives it the way to perform the save. Like a protocol "DataProxy" with implementations like "MemoryDataProxy", "FirebaseDataProxy", and you send it to the BaseDao (as the simple protocol DataProxy) and then just call DataProxy.save() or fetch(). And your proxy just have generic implementations and not specific to a table, thus can be provided by the dao object. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

change `UserDao` to a `class` or `struct`:

```
class UserDao: BaseDao {
    typealias Element = User
}
```